# Как правильно передать динамич. массив в поток и обновить его при изменении

Tags: массивы, delphi, многопоточность, динамические-массивы

Собственно ситуация программа для статистики. Делается выборка из блока данных по определенным правилам.

есть тип запись обьедененная в массив обьявляю так:

```
type
 TDataSection = record
  Data: TBytes;
  MD5: RecMD5uint64;
  PRuleN: uint32;
  NumBlock: byte;
  BtLen: word; //byte;
  SectUse: byte;
 end;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
....

  public
  FDDataSect: TArray<TArray<TDataSection>>;
  OutFDDataSect: TArray<TArray<TDataSection>>;
```

есть поток в нем обьявляю так

```
type
  TFindTr = class(TThread)
  private
 { Private declarations }
  public
  DataArr: TArray<TArray<TDataSection>>;
  RuleArr: TArray<TArray<TDataSection>>;

// исполняемая часть
procedure TFindTr.Execute;

 while CloseTR = 0 do begin // закрыть поток по внешнему требованию
  StatWork := 1;
  StopFind := 0;
  for NumRule := FStart to FEnd do begin
  Move((Pointer(DataArr[NumBlock,NumData].Data))^, n1arrB[0], SectLen);
  Move((Pointer(RuleArr[NumBlock,NumRule].Data))^, n2arrB[0], SectLen);
  NOutarr[0] := N1arr[0] xor N2arr[0];
  NOutarr[1] := N1arr[1] xor N2arr[1];
  NOutarr[2] := N1arr[2] xor N2arr[2];
  Move(nOutarrB, (Pointer(OutxorArr))^, SectLen);

  PacLenSect := 0;
  BsectSet := [];
  for nBt := 0 to SectLen - 1 do begin
 if OutxorArr[nBt] in BSectSet = false then begin
  include(BSectSet, OutxorArr[nBt]);
  inc(PacLenSect, 1);
  end;
  end;

//  првоверка на условия
  if (PacLenSect <= MinLenUse) then begin
  FindResult := 1;
  break;
  end;
  if StopFind = 1 then break;
  end;
  suspend; // ждем обновления данных из формы.
end;
```

обработка данных в форме

```
     // create potok
 x := 0;
 FindTR1 := TFindTr.Create(true);
 FindTR1.Priority := tpNormal;
 FindTR1.DataArr := FDDataSect;
 FindTR1.RuleArr := OutFDDataSect;
 FindTR1.FStart := 0;
 FindTR1.FEnd := Nrule - 1;

 for n := 0 to Ndata -1 do begin
 FindTR1.NumData := n; // задаем блок для обработки из иассива FDDataSect [x,n]
 FindTR1.Resume; // запускаем поток

  tmp1 := 0;
 while FindTR1.Suspended = false do begin // ждем окончания работы потока
  if (tmp1 mod 300) = 0 then begin
  tmp1 := 0;
  application.ProcessMessages;
  end;
  inc(tmp1, 1);
  end;

 if (FindTR1.FindResult = 1) then begin // если блок найдем в масиве OutFDDataSect 
  inc(NMinLen, 1);
  FindTR1.StatWork := 0;
  end;

// если блок ненайдем в масиве OutFDDataSect добовляем блок FDDataSect[x,n]

 if (FindTR1.FindResult = 0) and (n > 0) then begin 
  OutFDLen := length(OutFDDataSect[x]);
  Setlength(OutFDDataSect[x], OutFDlen + 1);
  OutFDDataSect[x, OutFDLen] := FDDataSect[x, n];
  inc(allFindNMinLen, 1);
  Nrule := length(OutFDDataSect[x]);
  FindTR1.FEnd := Nrule - 1;
  end;
```

Теперь собственно грабли.
Все Вычесления проходят в форме - результат правильный. повторяемость 100% - но ОЧЕНЬ медленно.

вычисления проходят в потоке БЕЗ ИЗМЕНЕНИЯ массива OutFDDataSect - результат правильный. повторяемость 100%

вычисления проходят в потоке С ИЗМЕНЕНИЯ массива OutFDDataSect - и тут начинаются грабли.
правильного результата нет. часто дожодит до зависания потока намертво.
при дебаге выяснилось что изменения линны OutFDDataSect не доходят до потока.

Вобщем чтото сделал не правильно, при попытке выяснить с помощь гугля и глубокого курения RTFM где именно результата не дало.
Причем такоеже обьявление прекрасно и стабильно работает в паралелльной сортировке массива OutFDDataSect методом инжекции.

Вобще буду рад любым подсказкам, желательно с кодом.

Ужк начал посматривать в сторону стандартной библиотеки System.Threading (Parallel Programming Library (PPL)) в принципе для моей задачи подходит...

---

> но поле RuleArr осталось прежним.

Это я понимаю. Специально убрал все попытки переинициализации FindTR1.RuleArr, чтобы подсказали вот здесь надо сделать так...

попытка добавить переинициализацию FindTR1.RuleArr после изменения массива результата не дала.

```
 ...... 
 setlength(FindTR1.RuleArr, 0);
 FindTR1.RuleArr := OutFDDataSect;
```

пока блок OutFDDataSect[x] находится в одном сегменте памяти - работает. как только сегмент сменился - грабли....

Вот и спрашиваю - Как ПРАВИЛЬНО провести переинициализацию дин. массива.

Писал софт в основном для АСУтп - а в нем не точто за указатели. за динамические массивы с работы вылететь можно.

Comment: Не углубляясь в детали, использование `application.ProcessMessages;` верный признак того, что вы что-то делаете неправильно.

Comment: Я, конечно, в данный момент с Delphi не связан, но у меня вопрос. В тэгах указана многопоточность. Но Вы запускаете дополнительный 1 поток и ждёте окончания его работы с помощью while. Это всё ещё похоже на однопоточное приложение, только костыльное. Почему бы тогда не создать несколько потоков для каждого TArray<TDataSection> ?

Answer (score 2):

У вас полностью отсутствует синхронизация.

**Синхронизация** - это обеспечение монопольного доступа потока к данным при их изменении. В данном случае, например, изменение длины массива приводит к тому, что он располагается на новом месте, а другие потоки об этом не знают и обращаются куда попало.

Тема синхронизации большая и сложная, в ответе её не объять. Для начала можете определить критические данные, к которым обращаются несколько потоков, например,  `OutFDDataSect`, и защитить доступ с помощью критической секции `TCriticalSection`: перед любым обращением к массиву входим в критическую секцию, после работы выходим из неё.

Или несколько изменить структуру хранения - вместо массива взять `TThreadList`, в который встроены примитивные средства разграничения доступа.

Даже  `while CloseTR = 0` нехорошо проверять в одном потоке, а изменять в другом, хотя это не приведёт к критическим сбоям. Для цели управления потоком можно использовать, например, события `TEvent`.

Что почитать - главу из Тейксейра/Пачеко, главу из Елманова/Тенцер,  [Многопоточность - как это делается в Дельфи](https://forum.vingrad.ru/forum/topic-60076.html)

Вот наколеночный пример, зачистку я уже не стал делать,  и хэндл окна в принципе может смениться.

На форме две кнопки и листбокс. Создаётся  массив на 800 мегабайт, заполняется случайными числами, запускается 8 потоков, каждый обрабатывает 100 мегабайт, ищет некую сумму четырех последовательных чисел.

Если поток нашел сумму, он кладёт данные в защищенный список, асинхронно сообщает об этом форме и приостанавливается, ожидая события.

Когда форме приходит сообщение, что в списке есть данные, она его блокирует, забирает данные, показывает их, очищает список. В списке из-за асинхронности могут быть данные из нескольких потоков - но только по одной записи из каждого. Форма сообщает каждому потоку,  приславшему данные, что он может продолжать работу, устанавливая соответствующее событие.

Вторая кнопка во время работы потоков вызывает полное завершение их всех. Это у меня сделано криво - не отслеживается, что потоки вообще созданы, что они работают и так далее - просто как пример управления.

```
const
  THR_MSG = WM_USER + 666;
  ASize = 100 * 1024 * 1024;
  ThrCnt = 8;

type

  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    ListBox1: TListBox;
    Button2: TButton;
    CheckBox1: TCheckBox;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    procedure THRMSG(var MSG: TMessage); message THR_MSG;
  end;

  TData = record
    Id: Integer;
    Position: Integer;
    Bts: TBytes;
  end;

  TTh = class(TThread)
  private
    Flist: TThreadList<TData>;
    FIdx, FDataStart, FDataLen, FCurrPos: Integer;
    // 0: immediate stop; 1: resume treatment
    FWinHandle: THandle;
    FEventHandles: array [0 .. 1] of THandle;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AList: TThreadList<TData>;
      WinHandle, ResumeHandle, StopHandle: THandle;
      Idx, DataStart, DataLen: Integer);
  end;
```

Форма:

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Src, ThrCnt * ASize);
  Flist := TThreadList<TData>.Create;
  Randomize;
  for i := 0 to High(Src) do
    Src[i] := Random(256);
  for i := 0 to ThrCnt-1 do
  begin
    EvHandles[i, 0] := CreateEvent(nil, True, False, nil);
    EvHandles[i, 1] := CreateEvent(nil, True, False, nil);
    TTh.Create(Flist, Handle, EvHandles[i, 1], EvHandles[i, 0], i,
      ASize * i, ASize);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to ThrCnt - 1 do
    SetEvent(EvHandles[i, 0]);
end;

procedure TForm2.THRMSG(var MSG: TMessage);
var
  i: Integer;
  List: TList<TData>;
  Data: TData;
begin
  List := Flist.LockList;
  try
    for Data in List do begin
      ListBox1.Items.Add(Format('th %d pos %d Data:[%d,%d,%d,%d]',
        [Data.Id, Data.Position, Data.Bts[0], Data.Bts[1], Data.Bts[2],
        Data.Bts[3]]));
      List.Delete(List.Count - 1);
      SetEvent(EvHandles[Data.Id, 1]);
    end;
    List.Clear;
  finally
    Flist.UnlockList;
  end;
end;
```

Поток:

```
constructor TTh.Create(AList: TThreadList<TData>;
  WinHandle, ResumeHandle, StopHandle: THandle;
  Idx, DataStart, DataLen: Integer);
begin
  inherited Create(False);
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
  Flist := AList;
  FIdx := Idx;
  FDataStart := DataStart;
  FCurrPos := FDataStart;
  FDataLen := DataLen;
  FWinHandle := WinHandle;
  FEventHandles[0] := StopHandle;
  FEventHandles[1] := ResumeHandle;
end;

procedure TTh.Execute;
var
  List: TList<TData>;
  WaitRes: Integer;
  Data: TData;
  i, sm: Integer;
begin
  repeat
    if FCurrPos < FDataStart + FDataLen - 3 then begin
      while FCurrPos < FDataStart + FDataLen - 3 do begin
        sm := Src[FCurrPos] + Src[FCurrPos + 1] + Src[FCurrPos + 2] +
          Src[FCurrPos + 3];
        if sm = 950 then begin
          Data.Id := FIdx;
          Data.Position := FCurrPos;
          Data.Bts := Copy(Src, FCurrPos, 4);
          List := Flist.LockList;
          try
            List.Add(Data);
          finally
            Flist.UnlockList;
          end;
          PostMessage(FWinHandle, THR_MSG, FIdx, 0);
        end;
        FCurrPos := FCurrPos + 4;
      end;
    end else
      SetEvent(FEventHandles[0]); // данные кончились

    WaitRes := WaitForMultipleObjects(2, @FEventHandles, False, INFINITE);
    if WaitRes = WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1 then; // продолжить обработку

  until WaitRes = WAIT_OBJECT_0; // ImmediateStop
end;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В тото и дело - специально удалил все попытки синхронизации. все только ухудшалось. Родитель и хозяин OutFDDataSect - TForm, все изменения В OutFDDataSect делает он. Поток при RESUME только читает из него данные и выставляет флаг FindResult. после чего засыпает и ждет другого запуска на поиск. При изменении OutFDDataSect  (TForm) нужно обновить  RuleArr в потоке. Вобщем нужен алгоритм параллельного поиска в массиве.

Comment: Ещё раз: `FindTR1.RuleArr := OutFDDataSect;` запомнило ссылку на массив. Когда длина `OutFDDataSect` изменилась, изменился и адрес, но поле `RuleArr` осталось прежним.

Comment: @Stalker n Если ответ помог, не забывайте о https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score -1):

пошговый дамп массива из формы и потока показал что данные доходят правильно. результат в потоке тоже верный. Проблема оказалась в необходимой задержке для остаканивания системы и потока после Resume. после введения sleep(10) все заработало. результат повторяемый правда сильно не стабильный. любой чих приводит к зависанию потока.Так-что пердача массива только для чтения через глобальную переменную - вполне правильный подход.

Костыль:

```
 FindTR1.Resume;
 sleep(10); // собственно сам костыль. 10 минмал время принятия по стаканчику для выхода из suspend.
 while FindTR1.Suspended = false do begin
```

В прцессе поиска среди плагиата созданного из одной статьи обратил внимание на TTask & TParallel.For
результат

TParallel.For - ну вот наконец-то перенесли аналог из FORTRAN-a - а нет. не туто было....
Нормально запустить не удалось. точнее заработало но так медленно что линейный алгоритм сильно обгонял.

TTask - заработало. код ниже. паралельность - только в таком виде работает. Сильно зависит от загрузки системы... ускорение от 2 до 2.8 раз.
Вобщем если нет желания заморачиватся с диспечером - можно использовать.

для проверки основного алгоритма сойдет. для нормальной работы софта - в принципе тоже.

Резюме по PPL Lib.
Ни о какой паралельности не и речи. Распределенные вычесления - да.(каждому потоку своя копия данных). Работа с общим блоком - только последовательно.... Вся прелесть паралельности теряется на копировании данных в поток...
Вобщем что этой библиотекой хотели сказать индусы так и осталось тайной, покрытой матом.

Отдельное Спасибо MBo за пример с потоками. По факту - раскуриваю книжку и буду разбиратся с примером. хотелосьбы получить стабильное ускорение процесса от 2.9 и выше.

Собственно рабочий  код с TTask

```
// WT, WTS и start/stoptime для подсчета времени - заменить как кому нравится......

uses System.Threading, System.SyncObjs, System.IOUtils;

type RecMD5uint64 = record
  MD5Hi: uint64;
  MD5Lo: uint64;
end;
type
 TDataSection = record
   Data: TBytes;
   MD5: RecMD5uint64;
   PRuleN: uint32;
   NumBlock: byte;
   BtLen: word; //byte;
   SectUse: byte;
 end;

 ..........

// TForm1 //
  public
   FDDataSect: TArray<TArray<TDataSection>>;
   OutFDDataSect: TArray<TArray<TDataSection>>;
   Ts2OutFDDataSect: TArray<TArray<TDataSection>>;
   FindResult: integer;
   TasksEnd: TBytes;

 ...........

procedure CreateTasksV2(DataArr, RuleArr:TArray<TArray<TDataSection>>; min, max: uint32; Pn: uint32; PNTask: byte; PtasksEnd: TBytes; var Wtasks: TArray<ITask>);
begin
 Wtasks[PNTask] := TTask.Create(procedure()
  var
    PNumRule: uint32;
    PnBt: uint32;
    N1arr: array[0..2] of uint64;   // calc xor sect
   N2arr: array[0..2] of uint64;
   NOutarr: array[0..2] of uint64;
   n1arrB: array[0..23] of byte absolute n1arr;
   n2arrB: array[0..23] of byte absolute n2arr;
    nOutarrB: array[0..23] of byte absolute nOutarr;
   BsectSet: set of byte;
   OutxorArr: TBytes;
   PacLenSect: uint32;
   Px: uint32;
   SectLen: uint32;
   MinLenUse: uint32;
  begin
   Px := 0;
   SectLen := 24;
   MinLenUse := 12;
   for PNumRule := min to max do begin
    setlength(OutxorArr, 24);
    Move((Pointer(DataArr[Px,Pn].Data))^, n1arrB[0], 24);
    Move((Pointer(RuleArr[Px,PNumRule].Data))^, n2arrB[0], 24);
    NOutarr[0] := N1arr[0] xor N2arr[0];
    NOutarr[1] := N1arr[1] xor N2arr[1];
    NOutarr[2] := N1arr[2] xor N2arr[2];
    Move(nOutarrB, (Pointer(OutxorArr))^, 24);
    //   tmp1 :=  CalcSectByteLen3T4(tmp);
   PacLenSect := 0;
   BsectSet := [];
    for PnBt := 0 to SectLen - 1 do begin
     if OutxorArr[PnBt] in BSectSet = false then begin
      include(BSectSet, OutxorArr[PnBt]);
      inc(PacLenSect, 1);
     end;
    end;

    if (PacLenSect <= MinLenUse) then begin
       PtasksEnd[PNTask] := 1;
       if PNTask = 1 then begin
        PacLenSect := 1;
       end;
    end;
   end;
  end);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button7Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 Tasks: TArray<ITask>;
 task: ITask;
 FStart, FEnd: uint32;
 FSectCount, FSectLen: uint32;
 FTrNum: uint32;
 FIn: TMemoryStream;
 NLoadRule, x, n: uint32;
 wt, wts, oldwts: RecTime;
 Ndata, Nrule: uint32;
 nresfind, nresnofind: uint32;
 s: string;
 NumRule: uint32;
 SectLen: uint32;
 OutFDLen: uint32;
 MinLenUse: uint32;
 NMinLen, allFindNMinLen: uint32;
 PacLen: uint32;
 FS: tstringlist;

 TaskRes: uint32;
 TasksecLen, TasksecLenEnd: uint32;
 BTasksEnd: uint32;
 Zt: uint32;
begin

 starttime(wt);
 x := 0;
 SectLen := 24;
 MinLenUse := 12;
 NMinLen := 0;
 allFindNMinLen := 0;
 setlength(FDDataSect, 0);     // clear
 setlength(OutFDDataSect, 0);      // clear
 FIn := TMemoryStream.Create;
 FIn.LoadFromFile(Memo1.Lines[0]);
 FIn.Seek(0, soBeginning);
 NLoadRule := FIn.Size div 24;
 setlength(FDDataSect, x + 1);
 setlength(FDDataSect[x], NLoadRule);
 for n := 0 to NLoadRule - 1 do begin
   setlength(FDDataSect[x,n].Data, 24);
   FIn.ReadData(FDDataSect[x,n].Data, 24);
 end;
 FIn.Free;

   setlength(OutFDDataSect, x + 1);
  OutFDLen := length(OutFDDataSect[x]);
   if OutFDLen = 0 then begin
     Setlength(OutFDDataSect[x], OutFDlen + 1);
     OutFDDataSect[x, OutFDLen] := FDDataSect[x, 0];
   end;
  Ndata := length(FDDataSect[x]);
  PBar1.Max := Ndata;
  TaskRes := 0;
  starttime(wts);
 for n := 0 to Ndata - 1 do begin // WORK

 NLoadRule := length(OutFDDataSect[x]);
 setlength(Tasks, 0);
 setlength(TasksEnd, 0);

// создаем потоки
 if NLoadRule <= 1000 then begin // 1 potok
  setlength(Tasks, 1);
  setlength(TasksEnd, 1);
 for BTasksEnd := 0 to Length(tasksEnd) - 1 do tasksEnd[BTasksEnd] := 0;
// procedure CreateTasksV2(DataArr, RuleArr:TArray<TArray<TDataSection>>; min, max: uint32; Pn: uint32; PNTask: byte;
//  var PtasksEnd: TBytes; var Wtasks: TArray<ITask>);
  CreateTasksV2(FDDataSect, OutFDDataSect, 0, NLoadRule -1, n, 0, TasksEnd, tasks);
 end;

 if NLoadRule > 1000 then begin
  setlength(Tasks, 4);
  setlength(TasksEnd, 4);
 for BTasksEnd := 0 to Length(tasksEnd) - 1 do tasksEnd[BTasksEnd] := 0;
  TasksecLen := NLoadRule div 4;
  TasksecLenEnd := NLoadRule - TasksecLen;
  CreateTasksV2(FDDataSect, OutFDDataSect, 0, TasksecLen - 1, n, 0, TasksEnd, Tasks);
  CreateTasksV2(FDDataSect, OutFDDataSect, TasksecLen, (TasksecLen * 2) - 1, n, 1, TasksEnd, Tasks);
  CreateTasksV2(FDDataSect, OutFDDataSect, (TasksecLen * 2), (TasksecLen * 3) - 1 , n, 2, TasksEnd, Tasks);
  CreateTasksV2(FDDataSect, OutFDDataSect, (TasksecLen * 3), NLoadRule - 1 , n, 3, TasksEnd, Tasks);
 end;

 FindResult := 0;
  for BTasksEnd := 0 to Length(tasksEnd) - 1 do tasksEnd[BTasksEnd] := 0;
  for task in tasks do
 task.Start;
 FindResult := 0;
 // for BTasksEnd := 0 to Length(tasksEnd) - 1 do tasksEnd[BTasksEnd] := 0;
   //Ждём выполнение всех задач.
 TTask.WaitForAll(tasks);
  FindResult := 0;
  for BTasksEnd := 0 to Length(tasksEnd) - 1 do begin
   if tasksEnd[BTasksEnd] = 1 then FindResult := 1;;
  end;
   if (FindResult > 0) then begin
   inc(NMinLen, 1);
  end;
  if (FindResult = 0) and (n > 0) then begin
   OutFDLen := length(OutFDDataSect[x]);
   Setlength(OutFDDataSect[x], OutFDlen + 1);
   OutFDDataSect[x, OutFDLen] := FDDataSect[x, n];
   inc(allFindNMinLen, 1);
  end;

    if (n mod 1000) = 0 then begin
   PBar1.Position := n;
   stoptime(wts);
   oldwts.start := wts.stop - wts.start;
   s := DecodeRecTime(oldwts);
   oldwts.stop := oldwts.start;

   memo1.Lines.Add(n.ToString +'   '+ s +'   '+ DecodeRecTime(wts));
   application.ProcessMessages;

   starttime(wts);
  end;
 end;
   stoptime(wt);
  memo1.Lines.Add(Zt.ToString + '  Dup  '+ NMinLen.ToString +'  Add  '+ allFindNMinLen.ToString +'  '+ DecodeRecTime(wt));
  Memo1.Lines.SaveToFile('LogTime');
end;
```

Comment: C Suspend извне потока рано или поздно можете столкнуться с проблемами, и отсутствие синхронизации (может быть, я её не заметил) одобрить не могу. Мой пример упрощённо моделирует вашу ситуацию, насколько я её понял, и обрабатывает 800 мегабайт в один поток за 2861 мс, в 4 или 8 потоков а среднем за 752 мс (у меня 4 core/4 threads i5-4670, и 8 потоков выигрыша не дают), т.е. распараллеливается хорошо, хотя я не стал делать асинхронную передачу, поскольку по сценарию события не очень частые.

Comment: с TTask - он у себя дублирует массив в потоке. Вобщем убрав все лишние движения блок из 300000 элементов обрабатывает с3 часов - до 42 минут. при не нагруженной системе. Всеравно много. 300К это 7мег - фойл 3 Гига. а файлов на 600 Гиг. Отсюда и уборка лишних телодвижений.
Такчто надо переходить на TThread.

Хотелось сделать как в Fortran-е Создал поток. запустил. посчитал. сообщил об окончании. ждем повторного запуска. без лишних телодвижений на  копирование массива и Suspend\Resume... тоесть - реальные параллельные вычисления, а не распределенные.

Comment: `ждем повторного запуска` - ThreadPool в threading это делает (сам не использовал). Про дубляж/копирование массива - мне непонятна нужда в этом.

Comment: procedure CreateTasksV2(DataArr, RuleArr:TArray<TArray<TDataSection>>; - Это обьявление с копированием

procedure CreateTasksV2(var DataArr, RuleArr:TArray<TArray<TDataSection>>; - без, компилятор выдает ошибку.

Comment: Какую ошибку?..

Comment: [dcc64 Error] Unit1.pas(549): E2555 Cannot capture symbol 'DataArr'    ошибка возникает здесь        Move((Pointer(DataArr[Px,Pn].Data))^, n1arrB[0], 24);

Comment: А, это тонкое место - var-параметр не может быть захвачен в контексте анонимной процедуры. Однако нужен ли этот параметр вообще, или вы можете обращаться к глобальной переменной массива?

Comment: через Form1.FDDataSect ........ заработало  правда забыл про эффект "нулевых данных" в паралельной обработке. пришлось ввести сортировку входных данных.  результат стабильный правда отличный от линейного. Слишком напрягает зависимость от нагруженности системы. В TTask можно задать приоритет выполнения задачи????

Comment: Вроде нельзя. Потоки же там по возможности от нас скрывают

Comment: Как не печально, но заработало - но не помогло. упорядочивание данных сьело весь выигрыш по времени. Вобщем надо браться за потоки.  Имеет смысл ковырять JVCL JvThread или не тратить время и сразу делать по правильному и как мне надо???

Comment: Про JvThread не знаю, впрочем, я и PPL в реальном коде не использую практически. А какие у вас получаются времена обработки для какого объёма данных? То, что я указал в первом комменте - для debug режима было, в релизе в 3-4 раза быстрее, но у меня, конечно, арифметики/расчётов там мало.

Comment: 800000/ 400000(all/ OutArr) 4 часа. Прогон на 48 часов. - результат мягко говоря MicroSoft-вский. Вроде работает. вроде в основном правильно. НО както криво. Иногда возникают флуктуации и считает не правильно. От чего зависит - не ясно.  Впечетление - от цен на селедку в Китае.  Вобщем для одноразового расчета (посчитал-забыл)  годится. для параллельной обработки массива 3,14\2,72 .Вобщем как нехотелось перехожу на потоки и SendMessage. Вобщем свои шишки тоже нужны - для лучшей усвояемости. )))

Comment: Да еще вопрос мало раскрытый в литературе. Чтение из потоков разных элементов массива  это будет считаться что потоки обращаются к разным данным или все таки к одним данным?

Comment: Если массив не меняется, то такое обращение в общем безопасно.

Comment: Про время обработки массива - со стороны непонятно, много это или нормально.

Comment: Мдя похоже только женские роианы и бульварное чтиво пишут для людей. тех-лит - самого себя потешить. типа напИсал... а что и как ... MBo с примером разобрался. Одна трабла - если по приходу message. лист залочен - оно теряется. ну и ResetEvent тоже нужен. Вобщем приостановка и повторный запуск наладил. Осталось сделать Break во время вычеслительного цикла. Вопрос можноли узнать установлено-ли снова событие после ResetEvent и какое. И узнать в каком состоянии TList - Lock/Unlock? А то после таких мануалов уже начал самневатся в способности логически мыслить...

Comment: Пока Break цикла решил через PostThreadMessage и PeekMessage, но хотеосьбы через SetEvent - ResetEvent.